# Query orderByChild in Firebase Realtime Database not working?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

I've seen many posts and solutions that are precisely what I need but when I implement it it doesn't work. I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database and I'm trying to search all "Name" children for a specific name. In this example I added the strings directly, but I'll be using a variable based on user input in the future. Here is my database structure as I see it in firebase:

```
{
  "kjienk24dfwefn" : {
    "FriendID" : "fr1959l9591i4925a",
    "Name" : "Test Dummy2",
    "email": "something@gmail.com",
    "Status" : "InGame"
  },
  "kjienk24kdfiwne" : {
    "FriendID" : "fr2812p8092m3604l",
    "Name" : "Test Dummy",
    "email":"some@something.com"
    "Status" : "Online"
  },
  "kjienk24udfjjo" : {
    "FriendID" : "fr7605h9204f8099g",
    "Name" : "Test Dummy3",
    "email": "fake@fakeemail.com"
    "Status" : "Offline"
  }
}
```

And here is the code I'm using to query the "Name" (usersRef points to "firebase.database().ref()"). I've seen lots of examples of this online and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
usersRef.orderByChild("Name").equalTo("Test Dummy").on("value", function(snapshot) {
    //This is where I expect to see Test Dummy on the console.  
    console.log(snapshot.val())
});
```

EDIT: Here is the initialization of usersRef. Haven't had any problems reading and writing to the database. Standard firebaseConfig.:

```
const fbApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db2 = fbApp.database("https://firebasedatabaseurl.com/")
const usersRef = db2.ref();
```

Test with parent node:
[image]

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: I posted an answer below, but in hindsight am not sure if that's what you're struggling with. 1) Can you replace the data structure you have with the actual JSON from the database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) It would also be good if we could see in the question how `usersRef` is initialized.

Comment: hi Frank, I added the export information. Changed the information but this is the exact structure I got when I exported. The "kjie..." are the userId's.

Comment: Hmmm, that looks fine at first glance. Can you also show how you initialize `usersRef`?

Comment: It works for me it seems: https://jsbin.com/soqinad/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I see in all the examples I've looked at you add an argument in ref("argument"). But since I'm referencing my main database node I left it blank. Would I just add the name of the database again?

Answer (score 0):

You want to load data from the `users` node, but that is currently not mentioned anywhere in your code. So Firebase is querying the root of your database, and the child nodes under there (like `users`) don't have a `Name` property, so you get no results.

```
const usersRef = db2.ref().child("users");
```

Or:

```
const usersRef = db2.ref("users");
```

Comment: I'm just not sure what I should put in ref() as there is no "users" parent node, they are children of my database "root" I believe.

Comment: In that case nothing is needed in there. Can you create a reproduction on a site like jsbin, as I've done in the comments and https://jsbin.com/soqinad/1/edit?js,console

Comment: You also shouldn't have to pass the URL in `fbApp.database("https://firebasedatabaseurl.com/")` if you already have it in the `firebaseConfig`.

Comment: I'll try and get something up on jsBin, i'll need to change the security rules. I know you said no snapshots but I posted one to make sure I am telling you correctly that my userId are children of the root.

Comment: regarding the database I have 3 seperate realtime databases so that was to configure the second one. I did it so it shares the auth state. In the firebaseConfig i have the default database URL.

Comment: hi frank, I added a node and added ref('Test') and it worked just fine. It seems it does not like to point to the root? I added a snapshot of the test data structure.